# Mongoose .insertMany and create function not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm quite new to the Mongoose and NodeJs, I'm working on a project to process some csv file and import the data to the database.
I used to have something like this: importDataToDb.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { SomeDatabaseModel } = require("../models/someDataBaseModel");

require("dotenv").config({ path: "../config.env" });


const dataJsonPath = "../dev-data/json_data/data.json";

const parsedJsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(dataJsonPath, "utf-8"));

mongoose.connect(`${process.env.DATABASE}`).then(() => {
    console.log("DB connected for import data");
});

class ImportData {
    constructor(model, data) {
        this.model = model;
        this.data = data;
    }

    async import() {
        try {
            await this.model.create(this.data);
            console.log("loaded ");
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
}

const importAwcMetar = new ImportData(SomeDatabaseModel, parsedJsonData );
importAwcMetar.import();
```

Since I only need to do this once in a while, I could just run `node importDataToDb.js` in the command line, this will work.

However, now I want to do this automatically in a route. This is the function that I will pass into the route.

```
module.exports.getDownloadFile = async (req, res, next) => {
    
    //not working, and will result server restart
    await SomeDatabaseModel.insertMany(parsedJsonData); 
    //not working, and will result server restart
    await SomeDatabaseModel.create(parsedJsonData);

    //This will work if I use the old method to import data into DB
    await SomeDatabaseModel.find({id: 'id1234'});

    res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
    });
};
```

For somehow this won't work, every time I run this route will result in a server restart.

This is what happened if I run `await SomeDatabaseModel.insertMany(parsedJsonData);`
[image]
The number of documents should be 4906, if I drop the collection in the MongoDB compass and run this function, a new collection will be created and I will have 0 documents.

If I do the same thing, which drops the collection and run
`await SomeDatabaseModel.create(parsedJsonData);`
The server will also restart, [image]
a new collection will be created, however, I won't get 4915 documents.
[image]

Another thing I noticed is, if I ran `node importDataToDb.js` directly in the command line, the `create()` would take a few seconds to finish, however, if I ran the function that will be passed into the route the server will restart almost immediately.

Comment: The function in module.exports doesn't seem to be connecting to the DB. Are you connecting before you execute?

Comment: @veryverde Yes. I could run ``findOne`` or ``find``, and I will get the correct results.

Comment: Server restart because of nodemon, you edit some file, nodemon watch the changes of the files' content.  You can start the server using `node server.js` and use try...catch to debug the `getDownloadFile` code.